# Reversing handlebar tape direction

Tags: handlebars, fixed-gear, handlebar-tape

Based on the [Park Tool guide on how to wrap drop handlebars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MzIiv7pewE), the bottom of the handlebars should have the tapes installed with an outward direction and reversing directions when it's on its way to the top.

The thing is, the guide is for drop handlebars with brakes/shifters in front. So I'm wondering, how does one reverse the tape direction if there are no brakes/shifters in front? Like say for a fixed gear where the brake is mounted on top of the bar?

Comment: Use hockey tape and don't worry about it.

Comment: There are handrests that duplicate the function of brake hoods without being brakes.  Often used on stoker bars on a tandem.

Comment: Does this depend what hemisphere the rider lives in ?  :)

Comment: I have never heard switching direction halfway before. Instructions from Park Tool are usually good but this one is just weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reverse the direction mid-way, as this would involve cutting the bar tape. You basically have two options:

- Do as stated in [your link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MzIiv7pewE) and start with an outward direction. You'll end up the other way round as shown in your video, which means you'll have to cut the tape the "other way".
- Start with an inward rotation in order to finish the same way as shown in the video.

---

Cool thing is, there are **no limitations** as there are no breaks. A few ideas:

**Go-naked carbonite**:
[image: naked_carbon]

**Simple and pure** (with an outward rotation at the start):

[image: simple]

**Fancy** (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Le43Tm6neVo) for instructions):

[image: fancy]

Comment: One of the two LBS that I go to start winding from the top forward. It has the advantage to work without any finishing tape around the last turn as when you begin at the end of the bar. And it looks very neat!